# Why does stackoverflow update the time elapsed on a question at 1 minute intervals?

Tags: discussion, usability

I noticed that StackOverflow updates the time elapsed counter automatically every 1 minute.

I find that feature to be virtually of no use. Is there any reason why they do it? Was it just to explore a cool new piece of technology (I suspect node.js is behind it) and see if they could do realtime updates?

Comment: Would you like this question migrated to the main meta.stackoverflow site where you'll be able to get an actual answer from the stack exchange development team?

Comment: Yes, if the stac exchange dev. team is monitoring that forum. I dont know how to move it. Could you do that for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its so that they can provide real time information to visitors about how fresh a question is and how long back it was posted or edited or updates. A lot of sites do provide real time updates as shown below

- [**Quora**](http://www.quora.com/)

[image]

- [**Twitter**](https://twitter.com/)

[image]

I also recommend reading this article : [Curators of the real time web](https://uxmag.com/articles/curators-of-the-real-time-web) for additional inputs. To quote an excerpt from the article

> Another focus is the speed of delivery, as well as how quickly content
>   can be presented or consumed. The real-time workflow is all about
>   speed—staying as close to moments of occurrence as possible. After
>   all, "breaking news" isn't breaking because it's being reported a week
>   after everyone else reported it. It's breaking because it's happening
>   right now. A volcano in Iceland was recently shooting plumes of ash
>   and rock 35,000 feet into the air and causing historic disruptions of
>   air travel. At one point in time that was breaking news. It might very
>   well still be news, but the real-time coverage of that event is no
>   longer important. It has already happened.

Comment: This looks like a very good reason. Especially for a site like Stackoverflow it could provide an indication of the freshness of a question. I will mark it as the answer if I dont see other alternatives proposed.

Answer (score 2):

On Stack Overflow hundreds of people watch tags all the time, and it's a race to answer questions because of this. Being the first (or one of the first) answers on a question is a big motivation because you're more likely to get upvotes and even an accepted answer. It doesn't always happen that way, but that's the way it happens most of the time.

The timestamp is meant to ask the question, "how long ago was this posted?" -- not "when was this posted?" This may seem like the same question but the motivation is different. Providing how long ago something was posted helps users determine (even just subconsciously) if they should answer a question.

Notice too that after the first hour, we no longer update by minute. It switches to hours. After 24 hours, it moves to days. After 7 days, then weeks. After 4 weeks, then months. And after a year, it moves to standard dates.